# Using a notation, find a recursive equation

Tags: recursion

$\ I_n = \int \cos^n \theta d\theta$

Find a recursive equation to express $\ I_n $ in terms of $\ I_n-_2 $. Find $\ I_6 $ and $\ I_7 $ as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos^n(x) = \cos(x)\cos^{n-1}(x)$ and try integrating by parts.
Also: remember that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

We show how to avoid explicit integration by parts. **Guess** that $f(x)=\cos^{n-1} x\sin x$ works. Check by differentiating. We get
$$f'(x)= \cos^n x-(n-1)\sin^2 x\,\cos^{n-2} x.$$
The first part looks good. For the second part, write $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$.

We get 
$$f'(x)=n\cos^n x-(n-1)\cos^{n-2} x.$$
It follows that 
$$n\int \cos^n x\,dx=\cos^{n-1}x\, \sin x +(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2} x\,dx.$$